# How to cultivate algorithm intuition?

Tags: algorithm

When faced with a problem in software I usually see a solution right away. Of course, what I see is usually somewhat off, and I always need to sit down and design (admittedly, I usually don't design enough), but I get a certain ***intuition*** right away.

My problem is I don't get that same intuition when it comes to advanced algorithms. I feel much more up to the task of building another [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com) then building another [Google](http://www.google.com) search, or a [Music Genom project](http://www.pandora.com/mgp.shtml). It's probably because I've been *building* software for quite some time, but I have little experience with *composing* algorithms.

**I would like the community's advice on what to read and what projects to undertake to be better at composing algorithms.**

(This question has nothing to do with [Algorithmic composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_composition). Well, almost nothing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

+1 To whoever said experience is the best teacher.

There are several online portals which have a lot of programming problems, that you can submit your own solutions to, and get an automated pass/fail indication.

1. http://www.spoj.pl/
2. http://uva.onlinejudge.org/
3. http://www.topcoder.com/tc
4. http://code.google.com/codejam/contests.html
5. http://projecteuler.net/
6. https://codeforces.com
7. https://leetcode.com

The [USACO training site](http://train.usaco.org/usacogate) is the training program that all USA computing olympiad participants go through. It goes step by step, introducing more and more complex algorithms as you go.

Answer (score 10):

You might find it helpful to perform algorithms physically.  For example, when you're studying sorting algorithms, practice doing each one with a deck of cards.  That will activate different parts of your brain than reading or programming alone will.

Answer (score 8):

Steve Yegge referred to ["The Algorithm Design Manual"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600) in [one](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/get-that-job-at-google.html) of his rants.  I haven't seen it myself, but it sounds like it's just the ticket from his description.

> My absolute favorite for this kind of interview preparation is Steven Skiena's The Algorithm Design Manual. More than any other book it helped me understand just how astonishingly commonplace (and important) graph problems are – they should be part of every working programmer's toolkit. The book also covers basic data structures and sorting algorithms, which is a nice bonus. But the gold mine is the second half of the book, which is a sort of encyclopedia of 1-pagers on zillions of useful problems and various ways to solve them, without too much detail. Almost every 1-pager has a simple picture, making it easy to remember. This is a great way to learn how to identify hundreds of problem types.

Answer (score 5):

## problem domain

First you must understand the problem domain. An elegant solution to the wrong problem is no good, nor is an inefficient solution to the right problem in most cases. Solution quality, in other words, is often relative. A simple scheduling problem that has a deterministic solution that takes ten minutes to run may be fine if schedules are realculated once per week, but if schedules change several times a day then a genetic algorithm solution that converges in a few seconds may be required.

## decomposition and mapping

Second, decompose the problem into sub-problems and known/unknown elements that correspond to elements of the solution. Sometimes this is obvious, e.g. to count widgets you need a way of identifying widgets, an incrementable counter, and a way of storing the count. Sometimes it is not so obvious. Sometimes you have to decompose the problem, the domain, and possible solutions at the same time and try several different mappings between them to find one that leads to the correct results [this is the general method].

## model

Model the solution, in your head at least, and walk through it to see if it works correctly. Adjust as necessary (See decomposition and mapping, above).

## composition/interfaces

Many times you can find elements of the problem and elements of the solution that map to each other and produce partial results that are useful. This composition and interface construction provides the kernal of the solution, and also serves to reduce the scope of the problem remaining. So then you just loop back to the top with a smaller initial problem, and go through it again.

## experience

Experience is the best teacher, of course, but reading about different kinds of problems and solutions will also be helpful. Studying some of the well-known algorithms *and their applications* is likewise very helpful, e.g. [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), [Bresenham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham_line_algorithm), [Unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification), and of course, [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_Theory).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure intuition can be cultivated, but I think I know what you are asking. The more problems you solve, the more information and experience you have at your disposal for future problems. So, I say just practice. Practice programming real world applications and you run into plenty of problems. Sometimes, solving puzzles can be very educational as well.

Answer (score 0):

I try to find physical analogues when I'm looking at a complex problem.